# How to merge Linux LVM physical volumes on the same disk?

Tags: lvm, lvm2

I have a funny situation (Proxmox, but that's immaterial) where I ended up with LVM, a single volume group on top of two partitions (PVs) that are contiguous with one another on the disk. The PVs (and the LVs on them) used to belong to different volume groups that I merged (they were named pve and pve-thin, now it's just pve, if you're curious)

What's the best way to merge the PVs? Is there even one other than the following steps?

1. Shrink the right PV as much as I can given the existing LVs, then create even MORE PVs until all of them (except the leftmost) are of a size that is less than the free space in the pool
2. Repeat [pvmove second, vgreduce second, delete second partition, extend first, update] until there's only one left.

I also have a question about moving my root volume into the thinpool but that's for later (and a bit sketchy as well).

P.S: In case this is the wrong site, please direct me to where I should actually ask. But it's a homelab so probably Server Fault is not appropriate?

Comment: "Merge" partitions isn't a thing in real world. It's dumbed down name some commercial partition manager softwares use to indicate what in reality is a scripted sequence of operations - move data, delete one partition, expand the other to the now unallocated space - something you CAN'T do with LVM. You can do the same operations but manually, with LVM tools: Backup the data of the 2nd partition somewhere else (to the 1st is fine if it has enough free space), remove the 2nd partition and expand the 1st to use the resulting unallocated space.

Comment: Yeah the first one is sadly the smaller one (it's currently hosting the root). I know I can do the merging with the shitty procedure within the question (thank God for GPT?), I'm asking if there's another _better_ way.